# Erroneour match using snowball analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

Iam using snowball analyzer for the stemming of the words. But this has mapped the words "insider" and "inside" to the same stem word "insid" which is totally wrong. How can I improve these kind of stemming of words in elasticsearch.

Comment: Why "totally wrong"? Have you tried other stemmers to compare?

Comment: No I didnt try any other stemmers.

Comment: Still why do you think it's "totally wrong"? As Evaldas mentioned in his answer the snowball analyzer simply does its job, just too agressively :)

Answer (score 0):

That's how snowball analyzer works. It's simply too aggressive. Based on my own experience, I tend to use modified [English analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer)

1. I remove `stemmer` filter as it's too aggressive. Just like snowball
2. I replace it with `kstem`, which is lightweight english filter. Does a great job.
3. I add `hunspell` dictionary token filter to normalize words (instead of `stemmer`)
4. I add `asciifolding` filter to normalize letter, so things such as `rôle` and `role` would be equal.

That would be it:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_hunspell" : {
          "type" : "hunspell",
          "language" : "en_GB"
        },
        "english_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_english_" 
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "kstem",
            "english_hunspell"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```